# [IOS]Only Support retina device

Tags: ios

I am really confused that if I only bundle @2x images, and I only have a layout for the retina screen. Will IOS scale it again?

For example, I pass point (800, 600) to opengl es, will IOS change it to (1600, 1200)? Cause I don't want to support non-retina device, so the (800, 600) is already the right position. But I am afraid the IOS will auto change it to (1600, 1200).

Comment: No it wont. Place on screen will be same. You can try putting few label on screen and try

Comment: [What does retina display mean?](http://www.medgadget.com/2010/06/apples_retina_display_what_does_it_mean.html)

Comment: please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738260/ios-app-non-retina-and-retina-images-concept/17738424#17738424 this you can clear your confutation

Answer (score 6):

On retina devices (iPhone 4, 4S, or 5, and iPad 3 or 4), there are 2 pixels per point. On non-retina devices, there is 1 pixel per point.

The except for the iPhone 5, all iPhones have a screen size of 320x480 points. The retina iPhones have a screen size of 640x960 pixels (but the same point size as the non-retina devices).

When working with images in iOS, it is the pixel size that matters, not the PPI. Just remember that your @2x images should have twice the width and height of the regular, non-retina images.

[Why doesn't self.view.frame.size.width change on the simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674334/why-doesnt-self-view-frame-size-width-change-on-the-simulator/17674460#17674460)

Comment: If only retina is supported, does it make any difference if all images are without "@2x"?

Comment: Doesn't mind..The same images will be used for both retina & non retina. Since your images are compatible with retina, the icons looks fair enough..I suggest you to test yourself by installing the app on retina device with naming convention as 1x