# Apple touch icon (iphone retina) not applied - something wrong?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icons, touch

I have 4 icons for my site:

- iPhone
- iPhone Retina
- iPad
- iPad Retina

They're all working perfectly apart from iPhone retina (144x144), which is just showing the usual low-rez iphone icon (57x57). Below is my code, please tell me what I'm doing wrong.. All paths/images/sizes are correct.

Thank you.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="app/img/touch-icon-iphone.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="app/img/touch-icon-ipad.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="app/img/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="app/img/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784288/iosonly-support-retina-device/17784334#17784334  you can get idea from here

Comment: Did you rename 114x114 images picture name with @2x ? imageName@2x etc

Comment: Perfect! Making it 'app/img/touch-icon-iphone-retina@2x.png' worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you rename 114x114 images picture name with @2x ? imageName@2x etc.

Answer (score 0):

set iPhone retina Image Name  `touch-icon-iphone@2x.png` . that is 144*144.